# while appending a file the data is not writing in a file and while reading it it shows null byte in python

Tags: python, linux, file, error-handling

I am writing a data in a file using append method of file handling but it is not being shown in a file.
Also while reading a file it shows a Null byte error.

```
with open("filename.txt",'a') as f_ro_panel:
    f_ro_panel.write('\n'+str(vl)+'\t'+str(op_minute)+'\t'+str(bcc)+\
           '\t'+str(temp)+'\t'+str(tds2)+'\t'+str(tds1)+'\t'+str(pfr)+\
           '\t'+str(rfr)+'\t'+str(rwpc)+'\t'+str(hppc)+'\t'+str(twv)+\
           '\t'+str(rwv)+'\t'+str(uvst)+'\t'+str(tsc)+'\t'+str(tlv))
    f_ro_panel.close()
```

This is the code of writing.

while reading I am using this program

```
with open("filename.txt", 'rU') as my_file:
    reader = csv.reader(my_file, delimiter='\t')
    my_list = list(reader)
    ListLen = len(my_list)
    my_file.close()
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Don't call `.close()` ath the end of your with block. The file is automatically closed when the `with` ends

Comment: Jsut to be clear, when you open the file with an editor you also don't see your printed text?

Comment: Reading from the [brochure](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#csv.reader) brother:  `If csvfile is a file object, it should be opened with newline=''.` You have an example of use there too.

Comment: I see no issue with code which is doing `write` operation, can you close while write operation is going on and once it is completed then open and check?

Comment: how do i check if the data is written or not in programming

Comment: Exactly FlyingTeller sir I don't see the new text in a file

Comment: Totally unrelated, but you should use the csv module to write your file too.

Comment: I have used that too. Actually, it happened after running this program throughout the night. And the data is written in every 20 minutes gap. And when I delete last line and again run the program it works fine for me.

Answer (score 0):

Few things you can check:

1. Variables v1, op_minute have correct values assigned to them
2. Check if you are able to read the current content of the file without appending anything (if the file already contains some data).There might be some issue with the delimiter.

I tried to run your code and it works fine for me.

Comment: This belongs to a comment, not to an answer.

Comment: I checked by reading the content in file and i found one gap between two line and find the data which i was trying to write

Comment: Please tell me what is the problem

Comment: I don't have the entire code with me so I cannot exactly point out where there is a bug. From what you have posted , it seems that the file in which you are appending is not correct(does not have proper delimiters etc.). So to debug the code break it down to pieces and check every section. I have provided you with steps how you can work on this problem. BTW.. what you are printing. Is it "my_list" or "Listlen" which is returning you NULL byte